# ClassicThesis in Spanish Language Using Lyx

Tags: lyx, captions, classicthesis, spanish

The problem is the following:

I'm using classicthesis to write my thesis, and I need the names of the captions displayed in spanish (e.g. "figura" instead of "figure"), so I uncommented the next line, in the `classicthesis-config.tex`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 \usepackage{babel}
```

So when I make the pdf from one chapter, the captions are displayed in spanish, but when I make the pdf from Classicthesis.lyx (the master document) the output pdf have the captions in english.

I tried changing the idiom of the master document and the child documents, but wasn't help. I don't know what other thing do, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you post a complete example?

Comment: Actually, the `classicthesis-config.tex` file should be considered an example of how to load packages and is not an essential part of `classicthesis`. It is a very badly written file, in my opinion. You can answer your own question, rather than editing it.

Comment: Thanks @egreg I don't have idea, let me changed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my own answer, I learned that Lyx only takes into account the preamble of the master document, so I changed language (spanish instead english) of this one in Document>Configuration>Language, but nothing happened.

I looked out the Tex code and I realized that Lyx first load the `classicthesis-config.tex` and after the Language option, this way:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% Classic Thesis Style loader
\makeatother
\input{classicthesis-config.tex}
\makeatletter
% use Latin Modern instead of Computer Modern sans serif
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\uspackage{babel}

\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\begin{document}
```

Then I commented the next line, in the `classicthesis-config.tex`:

```
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 %\usepackage{babel}
```

And I wrote `\usepackage[spanish, es-lcroman]{babel}` in the master document's preamble.

I hope this will be useful.